# How to merge two optional arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

How would you merge two optional arrays in Javascript these days? This is the best I got so far:

```
const trades = this.position.trades; // trades or maintenance can be undefined
const maintenance = this.position.maintenance;
const principals = [... trades ? trades : [], ... maintenance ? maintenance : []];
```

Looking for elegant solutions while dealing with the fact that either array can be undefined (aka optional). Thanks!

PS: I'm using Typescript 2.6 / ES6

Comment: Be careful of spacing after spread operator e.g. should be `...trades`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this. `||` this will return `[]` if the first operand is *falsy*.

```
const trades = this.position.trades || []; 
const maintenance = this.position.maintenance || [];
const principals = [...trades, ...maintenance];
```

Or instead of the `spread` operator just use [**Array#concat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
const trades = this.position.trades || []; 
const maintenance = this.position.maintenance || [];
const principals = trades.concat(maintenance);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `||` operator in conjunction with the spread operator which you already use:

```
const principals = [...this.position.trades || [], ...this.position.maintenance || []];
```